# What is the meaning of the Carriage Return symbol in MSO Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, carriage-return

What is the explanation (meaning) for the Carriage Return symbol shape in Microsoft Office Word? [image: Microsoft Office Word]

Answer (score 4):

The symbols have different meanings:

- ↲ - is used to indicate a line break where the *paragraph does not end*. This can be useful for formatting and presentation, especially as the formatting between paragraphs can be different. (not quite the same symbol as Word uses, apologies)
- ¶ - called a [Pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow), and originates from the middle ages. It indicates the end of a paragraph. As you can see from my screenshot below, Word (and many other things including web pages) have the concept of "*paragraphs*", allowing for formatting to be different between paragraphs (i.e: the additional space below), and for the first line of a paragraph to be indented, etc...

[image: example of text rendered by Word]

In HTML the above could be given as follows:

```html
<p>
  Paragraph 1, Sentence 1.<br>
  Paragraph 1, Sentence 2.
</p>
<p>
  Paragraph 2, Sentence 1.
  Paragraph 2, Sentence 2.
</p>
</p>
<p>
  &tab;Indented by a tab.
</p>
```

Comment: Based on my knowledge, "↲"  is also the Paragraph mark when you choose East Asian languages as Office display language, such as Chinese.

Comment: Oh interesting... do you know what they use in place of the Pilcrow in that situation? I wonder if there are other things I don't know about (like the concept of "_Paragraph_" being unsuitable perhaps?)... Would you be willing to share a screenshot that follows the format I've presented? (It would be good to include in my answer as a variation - or feel free to edit my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Carriage return is used as EOL (end of line) symbol, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes . Its english name is '*pilcrow*' in typography it is *alinea*. Its origin and meaning are listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow#Origin_and_name